# How to access foreign key of a model in a for loop

Tags: python, django

Trying to access a foreign key attribute, but I'm getting an error.

Here's my code:

```
for inbox in user_inbox:
    for i in inbox.post_set.all:
        print(i.title)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Inbox' object has no attribute 'post_set'
```

models

```
class Inbox(models.Model):
    ...
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, blank=True, null=True)


class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    title = models.TextField(max_length=95)
```

Any idea what the right way to access the foreign key is?

Edit:

I'm using the relationship I am because I want to create a link to the post in my inboxes. Here's the inbox html:

```
<div id="inbox_menu">
    {% for inbox in user_inbox %}
        {% for i in inbox.post_set.all %}
            <a href="{% url 'article' category=i.category id=i.id %}">
        {% endfor %}
    {{ inbox.text }}
```

Comment: Your edit does **not in any way at all** contradict what wencakisa points out. If you want that relationship, move the foreign key to the Post model.

Comment: How will that make it easier? What would my for loop look like in my inbox template?

Comment: It won't make it "easier", it will *make it do what you want it to*. And then your loop will be exactly as you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access foreign key of Inbox as shown in the following code.

```
for inbox in user_inbox:
    if inbox.post: # this is to check if post foreign key is in the inbox.
        print inbox.post.title
```

Comment: How would I access inbox.post.title?

Comment: print inbox.post.title

Comment: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'`

Comment: updated the code. You have made foreign key as null=True which allows to save as null.

Comment: Yep this works - it threw an error as many of them were `Null`. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

I think your logic is a bit wrong here. Usually, **one** `Inbox` has **many** `Post`s, not the reversed relation.

So you need to make a foreign-key relation in your `Post` model to your `Inbox` one.

```
class Inbox(models.Model):
    # ...
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Post(models.Model):
    # ...
    title = models.TextField(max_length=95)
    inbox = models.ForeignKey(Inbox, blank=True, null=True, related_name='posts')
```

Also, note that I added `related_name` field to the `ForeignKey` field. Now you can get your `Inbox` posts by doing `inbox.posts` instead of `inbox.post_set`. It's just more idiomatic.

And then in your loop:

```
for inbox in user_inbox:
    for post in inbox.posts.all():
        print(post.title)
```

Comment: Good point, although I'm not sure why you think that a customised name is "more idiomatic" than the default one.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think that it is just more straightforward to say `model.related_models` instead of `model.related_model_set`. But this is my point of view. @Zorgan can use whatever he wants.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the forward relation so you just use the name that you actually defined, ie `post`. The `_set` syntax is for the *reverse* relation, ie the one back from Post to Inbox, which would be `inbox_set`.

Comment: Sorry I phrased the question wrong. I want to access attributes of `Post`. So e.g. I want to access post.title. How would I do that.

Comment: Exactly as I said in the answer: via `post`.

Comment: So I want to access `inbox.post.title`. It doesn't let me do that. `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'`

Comment: Presumably because that specific inbox does not have a post associated with it. Did you set one? Where?